# Android: Facebook leaderboards - Scores API

Tags: android, facebook

I try to make a simple friend leaderboard for my application.

I did a lot of research in particular on the site and developer.facebook stackoverflow and I can't realize has a leaderboard.

I find the documentation lack of example and for a developer beginner , it is not easy.
On Stackoverflow I find a php code that seemed interested but I do not know myself in php

Here is where I am currently :

```
public class classement extends Activity{
public Button classement = null;



Bundle params = new Bundle();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.classement);

    params.putString("score", "3444");

classement=(Button)findViewById(R.id.classement);


classement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/scores",
            params,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    /* handle the result */

                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();



        /* make the API call */
        new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/scores",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    /* handle the result */

                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();

}

});

}
}
```

I apologize for my English
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Kindly explain the error you are encountering. I don't think folks on stackoverflow will be able to help otherwise.

Comment: I saw the need to put the app id in terms of httpMethode.GET
This is what gives me his "response : { Response : responseCode : 200 ... , error null"

For the parameter I can put any value , the score remains 0

after at the httpMethode.POST I must leave as "/ me / scores "
it puts me the following error :
" ... errorMessage : (# 3) Method only allowed for games }}"

Otherwise I have one more question to the levels of the display I manages how? For have a listfriend with their score.

thank you for your reply

Comment: er, ok . can you go to developers.facebook.com/apps/<yourappID> and in the settings make sure your app is in the category of "games" ?

Comment: Merci, maintenant je dois un message d'erreur 200: exigeons la permission à prolonger: publish_action. Je trouve cela: LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
    fragmentOrActivity,
    Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));. but i have always this error